# How to convert numpy bytes to float in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, type-conversion

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215100/how-to-convert-string-datatypes-to-float-in-numpy-arrays-in-python-3); I tried using genfromtxt but still, it doesn't work. Reads the file as expected but not as floats. Code and File excerpt below

```
     temp = np.genfromtxt('PFRP_12.csv', names=True, skip_header=1, comments="#", delimiter=",", dtype=None)
```

reads as `(b'"0"', b'"0.2241135"', b'"0"', b'"0.01245075"', b'"0"', b'"0"')`

```
     "1 _ 1",,,,,
     "Time","Force","Stroke","Stress","Strain","Disp."
     #"sec","N","mm","MPa","%","mm"
     "0","0.2241135","0","0.01245075","0","0"
     "0.1","0.2304713","0.0016","0.01280396","0.001066667","0.0016"
     "0.2","1.707077","0.004675","0.09483761","0.003116667","0.004675"
```

I tried with different dtypes (none, str, float, byte), still no success. Thanks!

Edit: As [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707650/evert) mentioned I tried float also but reads all them as none `(nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)`

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), and use `dtype=float` instead of `dtype=None`.

Comment: @Evert Yes I did, float gives all nan. Since it seems a simple thing, I spent roughly an hour looking for but nothing helped.

Comment: Is the second code block your input, or your output?

Comment: @Evert yes "reads as (b...)" Its output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use the `converters` argument:

```
np.genfromtxt('inp.txt', names=True, skip_header=1, comments="#", 
delimiter=",", dtype=None, 
converters=dict((i, lambda s: float(s.decode().strip('"'))) for i in range(6)))
```

(you'll need to specify a converter for each column).

Side remark Oddly enough, while `dtype="U12"` or similar should actually produce strings instead of bytes (avoiding the `.decode()` part), this doesn't seem to work, and results in empty entries.

Comment: This converter also works: `lambda s: float(s.strip(b'"')))` (that is bytestrings have a strip method as well).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fancy, unreadable, functional programming style way of converting your input to the record array you're looking for:

```
>>> np.core.records.fromarrays(np.asarray([float(y.decode().strip('"')) for x in temp for y in x]).reshape(-1, temp.shape[0]), names=temp.dtype.names, formats=['f'] * len(temp.dtype.names))
```

or spread out across a few lines:

```
>>> np.core.records.fromarrays(
...   np.asarray(
...     [float(y.decode().strip('"')) for x in temp for y in x]
...   ).reshape(-1, temp.shape[0]), 
...   names=temp.dtype.names, 
...   formats=['f'] * len(temp.dtype.names))
```

I wouldn't recommend this solution, but sometimes it's fun to hack something like this together.

---

The issue with your data is a bit more complicated than it may seem. 
That is because the numbers in your CSV files really are *not* numbers: they are explicitly strings, as they have surrounding double quotes.

So, there are 3 steps involved in the conversion to float:
- *decode* the bytes to Python 3 (unicode) string
- remove (strip) the double quotes from each end of each string
- convert the remaining string to float

This happens inside the double list comprehension, on line 3. It's a double list comprehension, since a rec-array is essentially 2D.
The resulting list, however is 1D. I turn it back into a numpy array (`np.asarray`) so I can easily reshape to something 2D. That (now plain float) array is then given to `np.core.records.fromarrays`, with the names taken from the original rec-array, and the formats set for each field to float.